# Odoo MissingError One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try again after refreshing

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-view

Odoo Warning,  MissingError  One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try again after refreshing.

Am  accessing  this  button  `action_four_weeks_schedule_form` which is shown  below  on .

```
<field name='multiple_ratecard_id' nolabel="1" options="{'reload_on_button': true}">  <!-- widget="many2many"-->
                                            <tree  string="ALLOCATE SPOTS" editable="bottom" >
                                                <button name="action_four_weeks_schedule_form" type="object" string="CREATE RATECARD SCHEDULE" class="oe_highlight" />
```

The `multiple_ratecard_id` is  a  many  to  many  to  a  model  called  singular  which has the  function  `action_four_weeks_schedule_form` in it
 This is  the  function

```
   def action_four_weeks_schedule_form(self,cr,uid,ids,context):
    for id in ids:
        order_obj = self.pool.get('ratecard.multiple').browse(cr,uid,id)
        my_id=int(order_obj.id)
    scheduled_for= order_obj.scheduled_for
    code= order_obj.code
    return {
        'name':_("Four  Week Schedule to Process"),
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_id': False,
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_model': 'four.weeks.schedule',
        'context':{'default_scheduled_for':scheduled_for,'default_code':code},
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'nodestroy': True,
        'target': 'new',
        'domain': '[]',
        'flags': {'form': {'action_buttons': True}}

    }
```

How can  i  solve  this error  and  have  the  button  pop out  the  view and  not the  Odoo Warning ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Restart the server
2. Update your module
3. Refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to access your module from another OS or Your module has access right issue, On Linux just give read and write access rights to "Others" for your module and restart the server.

Comment: The  error  was  not  due  to permission  errors  , it  was  caused  by  odoo  server  on  list  view  not  keeping  the  context  and  passsing  it  to  all  the  lines  in the  list  view  .... it  just  passed  the  context  to  the  first  line  ,  check  this  to  understand  more  of  what  i  mean  .....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335376/odoo-throws-a-missingerror-on-treeview-second-line-record