# How to pass custom context from another model to listview all elements added in a many2many

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-view

Model  A to  Model B  have  a  many2many  relationship  ,  in  listview  how can i  pass  context to  each  row added  and  use the  context to  pass  data  to button within the  listview for each row  added

Here  is  the  code

```
    class ratecard_multiple(models.Model):
    # pudb.set_trace()
    _name = 'ratecard.multiple'
    _rec_name = 'display_name'

    scheduled_for = fields.Integer(string='SCHEDULED FOR', default=1, track_visibility='always', store=True)

    multiple_ratecard_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='ratecard.sin.radio',
                                            relation='ratecard_multiple_singular_rel',
                                            column1='ratecard_multiple_id',
                                            column2='ratecard_sin_radio_id',
                                            string='RATECARDS')

class ratecard_sin_radio(models.Model):
    _name = 'ratecard.sin.radio'
    _description = 'RATECARD SINGULAR RADIO  '
```

I  want  to  pass the  value  of  scheduled_for  to each  row  added  in  multiple_ratecard_id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Context In Odoo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217665/passing-context-in-odoo)