# Odoo throws a MissingError On treeview Second line record

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-view

How  can  i  solve  this error  Odoo  throws  a  MissingError on  TreeView Second line button  when  clicked .
The  first Record  line works  but  i  need  such that for  each  record  on  the  tree the  code  below  will  be  able  to  pass the  contexts  and  open the  appropriate  view  . 
Kindly  assist

Here  is  the  code called  on  the  button

```
@api.multi
def action_four_weeks_schedule_form(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    res = {}
    ids = self._ids
    cr = self._cr
    uid = self._uid
    context = self._context.copy()
    for id in self.browse(self.ids):
        print  'id  in  ++++ ' , id
        order_obj = self.pool.get('ratecard.multiple').browse(cr,uid,ids)[0]
        ratecard_multiple_id=order_obj.id  #int(order_obj.id)
        # self.copy(cr,uid, id,ids, {},context)
        print  '##############################################'
        print  'ratecard_multiple_id', ratecard_multiple_id
        print  'action_four_weeks_schedule_form ratecard_multiple_id ' , ratecard_multiple_id
        scheduled_for= order_obj.scheduled_for
        code= order_obj.code

        print  'order_obj.multiple_ratecard_id.code' ,[ x.code  for  x in  order_obj.multiple_ratecard_id[0]]

        print  '##################################################################'
        for  lineitems  in  order_obj.multiple_ratecard_id:
            print  'Ratecard Codes of  selected  ' , lineitems.code
            singular_code = [ x.code  for  x in  order_obj.multiple_ratecard_id[0]]
            for  ln  in  lineitems:
                print  '***************************************'
                print  'ratecard singular name' , ln.name
                print  'ratecard singular code' ,  ln.code
                print  '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'
                # self.copy(cr,uid,id, ids , {},context)
                scheduled_for= order_obj.scheduled_for
                code= order_obj.code
                singular_code = [ x.code  for  x in  order_obj.multiple_ratecard_id[0]]
                print  '[ x.code  for  x in  order_obj.multiple_ratecard_id[0]]' , singular_code




        # for line in id:
        #     line_obj = self.pool.get('ratecard.multiple').browse(cr,uid,ids)[0]
        #     print  'line_obj contains' , line_obj
        #     print  '***************************************'
        #     print  'INNER  LOOP action_four_weeks_schedule_form   scheduled_for ' , line_obj.scheduled_for
        #     print  ' INNER LOOP action_four_weeks_schedule_form  code ' , line_obj.code
        #     print  'Can  i  get  code  of  selected   line_obj.multiple_ratecard_id.code  ' , line_obj.multiple_ratecard_id.code
        #     print  '@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'
        #     ratecard_multiple_id=line.id
        #     print  'inner line_obj  action_four_weeks_schedule_form ratecard_multiple_id ' , ratecard_multiple_id

        # scheduled_for= line_obj.scheduled_for
        # code= line_obj.code

    scheduled_for= order_obj.scheduled_for
    code= order_obj.code
    singular_code = [ x.code  for  x in  order_obj.multiple_ratecard_id[0]]


    print  'action_four_weeks_schedule_form   scheduled_for ' , scheduled_for
    print  'action_four_weeks_schedule_form  code ' , code
    print  'singular  ratecard  selected  is  ' , singular_code

    res = {}
    if scheduled_for == 2:
            view_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_two_weeks_schedule_form').id
            form_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_two_weeks_schedule_form').id
            tree_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_two_weeks_schedule_tree').id
            res = {
                'name': _('TWO WEEKS SCHEDULE FOR  RATECARD'),
                'view_type': 'form',
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'views': [(view_id, 'form'), ],
                'res_model': 'two.weeks.schedule',
                #  'res_id':self.id,
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'nodestroy': True,
                'target': 'new',
                'domain': '[]',
                'context':{'default_scheduled_for':scheduled_for,'default_code':code , 'default_singular_code':singular_code},
                'flags': {'form': {'action_buttons': True}}

            }
    elif scheduled_for == 3:
        view_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_three_weeks_schedule_form').id
        form_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_three_weeks_schedule_form').id
        tree_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_three_weeks_schedule_tree').id
        res = {
            'name': _('THREE WEEKS SCHEDULE FOR  RATECARD'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'views': [(view_id, 'form'), ],
            'res_model': 'three.weeks.schedule',
            #  'res_id':self.id,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'nodestroy': True,
            'target': 'new',
            'domain': '[]',
            'context': context,
            'flags': {'form': {'action_buttons': True}}

        }
    elif scheduled_for == 4:
        view_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_four_weeks_schedule_form').id
        form_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_four_weeks_schedule_form').id
        tree_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_four_weeks_schedule_tree').id
        res = {
            'name': _('FOUR WEEKS SCHEDULE FOR  RATECARD'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'views': [(view_id, 'form'), ],
            'res_model': 'four.weeks.schedule',
            #  'res_id':self.id,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'nodestroy': True,
            'target': 'new',
            'domain': '[]',
            'context':{'default_scheduled_for':scheduled_for,'default_code':code ,'default_singular_code':singular_code },
            'flags': {'form': {'action_buttons': True}}

        }
    elif scheduled_for == 1:
        view_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_one_week_schedule_form').id
        form_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_one_week_schedule_form').id
        tree_id = self.env.ref('ragtimeorder.view_one_week_schedule_tree').id
        res = {
            'name': _('ONE WEEK SCHEDULE FOR  RATECARD'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'views': [(view_id, 'form'), ],
            'res_model': 'one.week.schedule',
            #  'res_id':self.id,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'nodestroy': True,
            'target': 'new',
            'domain': '[]',
            'context':{'default_scheduled_for':scheduled_for,'default_code':code , 'default_singular_code':singular_code},
            'flags': {'form': {'action_buttons': True}}

        }
    else:

        view_obj = self.pool.get('ir.ui.view')
        view_id = view_obj.search(cr, uid, [('model', '=', self._name), \
                                            ('name', '=', self._name + '.view')])
        res = {
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_id': view_id or False,
            'res_model': self._name,
            'context': context,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
            'flags': {'form': {'action_buttons': True}}


        }

    id.update({
        'radio_scheduled_for': scheduled_for,
        'update_code' : code,
        'singular_code' : singular_code ,
    })
    return res
```

This is  the  screenshot of the  error the  button  pressed  throws  this   error
[image]

Comment: MissingError only when system will not find id of record. ID will search/browse in database if the id is not found with related model than it will give error like MissingError. So we need to focus on id and related model.

Comment: On  first  record  in  tree  view  the  CREATE SCHEDULE  works , but on  second  and  the  lest it doesnt, how  can  i  make  sure the  record is  found for  all  lines  in  tree  view